# How should I deal with my leg being tired at the fourth day after the overexertion?

Tags: exercise, muscle, legs

For days ago, I run backwards and my thies still hurt (just like muscles hurt when they're exerted). Is that a sign of any injury?

Answer (score 1):

Not neccessarly. If you're in acute pain then you should definitely go to the doctor or emergency room.

But I've recently overexerted myself biking and jogging and it took about 5 days for my aching calf muscles to get back to normal.